# VR Navigation with Gravity

Tags: navigation, vr

When navigating with VR using the "VR Scene Inspection" add-on, is there a way to enable gravity for the viewer while moving? For example, when using Blender's normal walk navigation (not VR), you can enable gravity for the view by hitting the TAB button and your movement will automatically follow the height of the surface you are traversing, however this does not seem to also work when navigating in VR.

Comment: I know nothing about VR, but [this](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/3d_view/vr_scene_inspection.html#vr-scene-inspection) is the full section in the Blender manual about it and the first paragraph does say " More advanced use cases may be enabled through further development inside of Blender." so what you want may appear in future if you can't find it now.